# Dynamic casting of base class to child in c#

Tags: c#, exception, casting

I have a base class and two child classes with one class having additional fields. The function takes a base class as argument and casts it to child class at run time but casting base class to class B gives error

```
public class Base {
       int x
  }

public class A :Base {
    A() { x= 5;}
      }
public class B :Base {
   int y ;
   B() { x=5
        y=5;
      }
  }
```

while casting base class to child at run time, it throws invalid cast operation error

```
public int getValue(Base base) {
      A a = base as A //works fine
      B b = base as B // throws invalid cast opertions
      return (a.x + b.x + b.y)
    }
```

It should work because both the classes inherit from base but cant figure out why it fails on class B.

Why is that?

Comment: You can call `getValue` with either an instance of Base or of A, since A is a subclass of Base. You can't call it with a B, since B has no base class, except `object`. The `as ` operator doesn't throw, it will simply return a null if the cast fails. Since B is not a subclass of Base, then your ` base as B` expression won't compile

Comment: Also, if `getValue` takes any `Base`, not just `A` instances, if you call it with simply a `Base` instance, `base as A` will return null, so `a.x` would throw if that could did compile and you based it a `Base`

Comment: Either your example doesn't match your question or you forgot to inherrit from Base class in B class.

Comment: `public class B : {` is invalid code - please check  what you've posted (see [MCVE] guidance on posting code). Assuming `public class B : Base { ...` as your post claims you should not be getting the error you claim...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes,I have edited that

Comment: Please do not use `base` as an identifier in C#; it is too easily confused with the `base` access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very logic, only if the instance of base is class B, the cast is possible. I made a small example to explain this better:

```
public class BaseClass
  {
    public int x { get; set; }
  }

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public A() { x = 5; }
}
public class B : BaseClass {
    public int y { get; set; }
    public B()
        {
            x = 5; y = 5;
        }
    }
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass bClase = new BaseClass();
        A a = bClase as A; //a = null
        B b = bClase as B; // c = null

        BaseClass bClase2 = new A();
        A a2 = bClase2 as A; //works fine
        B b2 = bClase2 as B; // b2 = null

        BaseClass bClase3 = new B();
        A a3 = bClase3 as A; // b2 = null
        B b3 = bClase3 as B; //works fine
        //Cast down = ok
        BaseClass bb = bClase3 as BaseClass;

    }
}
```

PS: For future use of stackoverflow, please provide working code. Makes your helpers live easier.